# Why am I getting the message that the search-bar is not intractable?

Tags: python, selenium

The code is supposed to type "fish" into the YouTube search bar using Selenium and a Chrome Browser.

I have tried the xpaths of mulitple divs that hold the  tag and they didn't work either.(not sure if the error was the same though) The xpath in the code is for the `<input>` tag so it should be fine.

I also watched a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/f7LEWxX4AVI) and the xpath was exactly the same so that shouldn't be the problem since it worked for the YouTuber.

It also took me some time to figure out that the `find_element_by_*` are depreciated functions.

Could it be that the `.send_keys` has also been changed? I did try to find the selenium changes in 4.1.0 and it said nothing about it on a website that I found.

Should I maybe delete Selenium 4.1.0 and install an older version? For simplicity sake. Since there is probably a bigger number of tutorials for it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

setting = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
setting.add_argument("--incognito")

# I open the browser in incognito just so I don't clutter my search 
# history with dumb stuff as I'm testing things out
# could it be a part of the problem?

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = setting)
driver.get('http://youtube.com')

searchbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search"]')
searchbox.send_keys('fish')
```

Error Message:
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)                                    
driver.get('http://youtube.com')
searchbox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#search")))
searchbox.send_keys('fish')
```

In order to send_keys to that element wait for it to interactable and then send keys.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you so much! So the problem was the loading speed. The program tried to input text even thought the site still didn't load right?

Comment: That and using unique selectors. //*[@id="search"] returns 5 elements which makes a g tag your first element which is uninteractable since it's not an input tag you could have just used (//*[@id="search"])[3] instead.

Comment: Ok great, thanks :)